# NVIDIA GT 740 is not detected but fan is working

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios, ubuntu-16.04

I have just installed a graphic card NVIDIA GT740 on my motherboard ASUS P8H61-M. I'm connecting the monitor in the VGA port and it shows "No signal", although graphic card's fan is working, so I guess it is well plugged on the PCI. If I connect the monitor in the integrated card, it works fine.

I'm on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine and if I run `lspci`, graphic card is not shown; it's not detected. I'm stuck and I don't know what to do more.

This is my BIOS info:

```
Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
Version: 0702
Release Date: 10/09/2012
Address: 0xF0000
Runtime Size: 64 kB
ROM Size: 8192 kB
Characteristics:
PCI is supported
BIOS is upgradeable
BIOS shadowing is allowed
Boot from CD is supported
Selectable boot is supported
BIOS ROM is socketed
EDD is supported
5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
Serial services are supported (int 14h)
Printer services are supported (int 17h)
ACPI is supported
USB legacy is supported
BIOS boot specification is supported
Targeted content distribution is supported
UEFI is supported
BIOS Revision: 4.6
```

I see that BIOS can be updated, can it be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the card is properly inserted into PCI-E slot. Maybe not all contacts have touch...

Also check the PCI-E slot for some rubbish, wouch could block contact. If it doesn't help, try the card in different PC. If it isn't detected even there, the card is probably faulty. If it gets detected, you may have problem in your motherboard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try that. Is it possible the graphic card to be bad connected to the slot even if its fan is working?

Comment: The most probably yes. The fan is controlled by the BIOS of the GPU (and later drivers), so if the card has sufficient power, it can trigger the fan. But it may not have connected all data contacts and therefore isn't detected.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. I will try those things.

Comment: Also check the BIOS/UEFI settings, obviously. And that even before thinking about updates. Some older MBs automatically enable the discrete and disable the integrated. Now, most require that you explicitly choose it, integrated, discrete or both (multi-monitor enabled boards only).